# Using ES6 with gulp

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6, gulp

I am using gulp and I have written a build task for my angular js webapp project. but gulp does not understand arrow functions that I have used in my scripts so it gives me such errors like:

    `error  Parsing error: Unexpected token >`

so whats the possible solution? I have tried Babel too!

Comment: Show us your gulp file.

Comment: Not exactly clear, is it gulp not understanding your gulpfile because of ES6 features or is it the browser not understanding the output of your gulp task?

Comment: @minusfour actually all my javascript files are in es6 and gulp gives me a console error when I try to build.

Comment: Upgrading `node` is your best solution IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Currently using ES6 arrow functions in my build with no problem. Make sure you have at least version 3.9 of both the CLI and local version of gulp. To check which version you have, open up terminal and type: gulp -v.
[image]

```js
gulp.task('styles-production', () => {
  return gulp.src('.tmp/styles/main.css')
    .pipe($.cssnano())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/styles'));
})
```

[image]

Comment: actually all my other javascript files are in es6 and gulp does not understand them

Comment: Wrong answer then. I thought you meant the gulp tasks were failing.

Comment: it is 3.9.1 @Alex

Comment: Check if your browser supports ES6 style syntax. Arrow functions work in Chrome Canary with the chrome://flags/#enable-javascript-harmony flag enabled.

Comment: A screenshot of your error would also be really helpful, your problem is not very clearly.